# bitwise left shift in Java produces the same values...?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm writing a left shift algorithm in Java and have been doing some left shift calculations by hand.  All of these numbers are typed as **byte**, btw.

Let's say I'm working with 8-bit integers from -128 to 127.

Then from my calculations:

```
(-113 << 4) == (-65 << 4) == -16
```

because

```
-113 == 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
-113 << 4 == 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 == -16
```

but so does

```
-65 == 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
-65 << 4  == 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 == -16
```

So left shifting -113 by 4 and left shifting -65 by 4 result in the same value?  Shouldn't all left shift operations produce unique values?  Or do I have this right?

**EDIT:**

I'm working in Java and all of my numbers are bytes and the JVM is throwing an "error: loss of precision error" and this is what is also precipitating my question. 
Thanks!

Comment: The question isn't clear. What are you trying to figure out?

Comment: This is how it work. "every bit in the operand is simply moved a given number of bit positions, and the vacant bit-positions are filled in, usually with zeros (contrast with a circular shift)."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift

Comment: Since these are negative values you'll probably want to preserve the sign bit, but as Amit says it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Edited.  Is it more clear?

Comment: @M.M Well, I'm working with Java.  My code is as follows:  byte << byte and it's not compiling, throwing loss of precision...So I guess you can't shift with Bytes in Java?

Comment: @M.M Good call on the language tag.  I've edited for clarity.

Comment: "Shouldn't all left shift operations produce unique values? " No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This and many more shifting-related questions have been discussed in-depth in an SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work). It also explains why your bits are counted differently when using signed expressions.

Concerning your question:

The *same value from different source values* issue you encountered comes from the fact that you're throwing information away by left-shifting bits out of the word. One of the formerly number-related information carrying bits has in both cases become the sign bit.

If you would have shifted -16 by only three bits, you would have even ended up with a positive number:

```
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 = 120
```

And, if you shifted out all of the bits (`<< 8`), you will also end up at the same value:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = 0
```

So you can indeed come up with the same number by shifting the bits of different values.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, Jan.  Makes sense!

Comment: Glad that helped. If you want the behavior you described (i.e., not lose information and always get a different number), you might want to look at **rotation** instead of shifting.